# Add event to DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, events, xaml

How can I add `SelectionChanged` event to this XAML code?

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="stcombo" 
                        CellStyle="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle}" 
                        Header="Статус" 
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding name_ru}" >
    ???                        
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Any effort? What have you tried? Why it fails? Voting to close as non-constructive.

Comment: Let's be a little more precise here: I assume you want to subscribe an *event handler* to that UI element through XAML? Or do you truly want to define, in XAML, the *event* itself?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can add a SelectedChanged event of a datagrid combobox. The alternative solution is -

You can bind a property to SelectedItem of a combobox and use setter of this property to handle the selectedchanged event logic.

The setter will gets execute whenever user select any value from combobox.

XAML -

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn CellStyle="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle}" x:Name="stcombo"  Header="Статус" SelectedItemBinding ="{Binding SelectedCustomer,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Code behind /Viwe Model

```
private Customer _selectedCustomer;
public Customer SelectedCustomer
{
    get
    {
       return _selectedCustomer;
    }
    set
    {
       _selectedCustomer = value;
       //Do your custom logic
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just a sample code, you can replace the Customer to type which gets binded with combox.

Answer (score 1):

With this lines

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="stcombo" 
                        CellStyle="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle}" 
                        Header="Статус" 
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding name_ru}">

    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
           <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="yourCBSelectionChanged" />
      </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>   


</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

In code:

```
private void yourCBSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     //Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath=" "
                      SelectedValuePath=" "
                      SelectedValue="{Binding  }"
                      SelectionChanged="" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: but x:Name="stcombo" is not visible if i try this

Comment: you can use binding...what u want to achieve with name

Comment: "is not visible" .... look at the answers of your other questions. Don't post similar questions every 20 minutes.

Comment: Tried this bit it fires the event for each row when the table is loading